# Is the below list complete for installing Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, kde

Is the below list complete for installing Debian? I just pick them from long list.

debian-live-7.6.0-i386-kde-desktop.iso
debian-live-7.6.0-i386-kde-desktop.iso.contents
debian-live-7.6.0-i386-kde-desktop.iso.log
debian-live-7.6.0-i386-kde-desktop.iso.packages
debian-live-7.6.0-i386-kde-desktop.iso.zsync

There's a lot of other stuffs there on website, ie: Rescues, Standards, Sha, MD5, .zync, etc.

I cant identify which are complete set for downloading, long list?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the .iso file.

This is the image you need to burn to CD or mount on your VM to install debian from.

The sha and md5-sums are the checksums of the iso files. You can [run an md5sum check](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows) against the downloaded file to check it's integrity.
If the md5sum corresponds to the one on the server, you can be sure your iso has downloaded correctly.

This check is not necessary though, it's just to be safe.

Comment: I only have USB, I went to the website, just having a hard time to pick what is needed from that long list. I know they are not all needed, just need to pick, I just dont know which. Please help.

Comment: Can you please view here - http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/i386/iso-hybrid - Then advise which to pick among that long list? Do I need to pick only one file? Or a set of files?

Comment: Are you on Windows?

You can use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to flash the ISO file to your USB drive.
Then you should be able to boot from this USB drive (you might need to select it at boot time from BIOS).

The ISO you need depends on your needs.
[These](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/) are live-cd's, you can run the system from the CD.
GNOME desktop environment is default.
You seem to want to go for KDE desktop environement, then you should choose that image.

You can find more help for choosing the correct image [here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/).

Comment: You only need the .iso image, really.

Comment: So you mean I just need to download one file (only this file kde-desktop.iso)? How about the others - kde-desktop.iso.contents, kde-desktop.iso.log, kde-desktop.iso.packages, kde-desktop.iso.zsync ? Or what else, it's a long list, what are the others need for?

Comment: The .log, .zsync, .packages are just informational to let you view how the images have been built, which packages they include etc.
The SUMS files are as I explained above, the .sign is proof that they are signed by Debian and not been tampered with.


The other .iso images are different flavors of Debian, you can read about them [here](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/).


Basicly they come with different standard Desktop Environments.
[This](http://www.engadget.com/2012/11/30/how-to-pick-a-desktop-environment-in-linux/) may help you choose.

Comment: Thank you very much. Last one, which is better? Stable, Testing, or Unstable? I asked because they say Stable is not up to date with latest technology? Isn't it?

Comment: @HaberCasio, this really depends on what you are looking for. You seem pretty new to Debian so I would recommend Stable. Testing is nice but you need to be able to fix things **if** they break. Testing is indeed more up to date, it is the next stable version of debian where all the packages get tested. Unstable is the version after that and is really only for Debian contributors/developers.

Comment: @ aairey : Can you answer my other post please (separate question). see my post earlier

Comment: @HaberCasio, please ask again or link me as I can't see what is left to be answered.